# Filter two timestamps on dataframe using spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Scala "2.12.10" and Spark "3.4.0".

I read a Postgres table using dataframe and my dataframe looks like this:

| userID | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.02 | 2023-01-28 19:22:59.266508 |
| 1 | 2.02 | 2023-01-28 20:22:59.266508 |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-02-28 12:21:34.466508 |
| 2 | 18.32. | 2023-01-18 01:34:01.222408 |

I would like to filter each row from the dataframe and accumulate the amount (sum) if two conditions happens: if the registers belongs to the same user and if the date is before, producing a new dataset like this:

| userID | amount | date | acummulated_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.02 | 2023-01-28 | **12.04** |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-02-28 | **17.04** |
| 2 | 18.32 | 2023-01-18 | 18.32 |

**Note that the first line of the result accumulated with the same day (accumulated two first lines)**

**Note that the second line meets the requirements (accumulated the first 3 lines)**

How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Why you summed the amount for 2 dates 2023-02-28 12:21:34.466508 and 2023-01-28 20:22:59.266508 into one date 2023-02-28 12:21:34.466508 ?

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb because the timestamp doesn't matter for me. I would like to sum each day in a acummulated way for a given user.